# Restrict Opportunity stage-8 close-won if it had zero contact role

Tags: visual-workflow, validation

I am trying to create any validation rule or flow for the restriction of the opportunity stage change to close-won as this opportunity contains atleast 1(one) contact role. So without any contact role the opportunity cannot move to stage-8 won.
Can anyone pls help me with the navigation and which process I should follow?

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as [your previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/419573/is-it-possible-to-create-a-validation-rule-for-opportunity-and-contact-roles)? The only difference appears to be the stagename you're targeting, and the answer you got on your other question should be equally valid here.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a flow that triggers on the opportunity, and provides validation if the conditions are met. That would look something like this:

[image: Flow to stop opportunity save when conditions are met]

I leave the specific implementation of the conditions to you; this should have enough detail to get started. The Assignment element is just assigning a Number variable using the Equal Count operator to get the number of Contact Roles that were queried in the previous step, which the Decision then uses to determine if the error should be shown.

Comment: Hi thanks for creating the flow , can you please share the screenshot of all the edit elements including in this flow like decision,get record, assignment, decision too